# Echo some string and multidimensional array element in one line of code

Tags: php, string, multidimensional-array, echo

I've been struggling with some weird thing about php for a while.

It seems as if it is unable to display some string and a multidimensional array element using one line of code.

For example we have a simple 3d array:

`$ARRAY = array('first' => array(array('Hello, World!')));`

Now if I want to display some string and that 3rd level element, I'll have to do something like this:

```
$a = $ARRAY['first'][0][0];
echo"Some string: $a";
```

Or this:

```
echo"Some string: ";
echo($ARRAY['first'][0][0]);
```

So is there any way to actually do it in just one line of code?
Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
echo "Some string: {$ARRAY['first'][0][0]}";
```

Read more at [PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

> **Complex (curly) syntax**
>
> This isn't called complex because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.
>
> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to get a literal {$. Some examples to make it clear:

Answer (score 2):

Use [concatenation](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-string-concatenation.html):

```
echo "Some string: " . $ARRAY['first'][0][0]);
```

or

```
echo "Some string: ", $ARRAY['first'][0][0]);
```

Comment: No idea why I haven't thought of that, have been using concatenation for a long time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`echo "Some string: {$ARRAY['first'][0][0]}";`