# php help: I have an array as a property of an object, and i cant seem to call the items in the array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a object 'aff' with an array 'bill' as a property.

```
var_dump($aff);
echo "<br/>";
print_r($aff->bill);
echo "<br/>";
var_dump($aff->bill);
echo "<br/>";
echo "<br/> $aff->bill[0]";
```

This returns:

```
affiliation Object ( [id] => 1 [afname] => TaylorGang [user1] => 18 [user2] => 19 [user3] => 0 [user4] => 0 [value1] => 65.432 [value2] => 52.14 [value3] => 0 [value4] => 0 [bill1] => Grape Soda [bill2] => Cable [bill3] => empty [bill4] => empty [due_date1] => 18 [due_date2] => 15 [due_date3] => 0 [due_date4] => 0 [startdate] => 2014-07-21 22:03:21 [user] => Array ( [0] => 18 [1] => 19 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 ) [bill] => Array ( [0] => Grape Soda [1] => Cable [2] => empty [3] => empty ) [value] => Array ( [0] => 65.432 [1] => 52.14 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 ) ) 

Array ( [0] => Grape Soda [1] => Cable [2] => empty [3] => empty ) 

array(4) { [0]=> string(10) "Grape Soda" [1]=> string(5) "Cable" [2]=> string(5) "empty" [3]=> string(5) "empty" } 

Array[0]
```

I would expect that:

```
echo $aff->bill[0];
```

would return: 'Grape Soda'

If anyone could explain why this does not work and more importantly how I can get it to work it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your code instead of debugs?
Looks like your property is private or something.

Comment: All properties are set to public are set as public. Why would $aff->bill[0] not exist i have an array  'bill' in my object 'aff'?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Echo some string and multidimensional array element in one line of code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085570/echo-some-string-and-multidimensional-array-element-in-one-line-of-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string contains a complex expression, so you should wrap it up in curly braces:

```
echo "<br/> {$aff->bill[0]}";
```

Or, don't put the expression *in* the string (use concatenation):

```
echo "<br/> " . $aff->bill[0];
```

Without the curly braces, the `[0]` part is ignored as part of the expression, effectively leaving PHP to output the type of the object ("Array"), after which it treats the `[0]` as just part of the text, so the final output is effectively `"<br/> " . "Array" . "[0]"`.

[Read More](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)

Comment: You should also update your PHP to 5.4or 5.5 (not sure which from top of my head) and enable higher error reporting level, that would have warned you about an array to string conversion

Comment: How would this work for an if statement                                            '<?php if ( {$aff->bill[0]} == 'Grape Soda') {echo 'worked';}?>             this results in an error and php storm underlines the curly braces in the if statement

Comment: @user3692109: You would not use the curly braces anywhere except when you're doing the array-access *within* a string. I added another example.