# Echo with the result of a multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is my code:

```
<?php
$contacts = array($alena = array("name" => "Alena Holligan",
                                 "email" => "alena.holligan@teamtreehouse.com"), 
                  $dave = array("name" => "Dave McFarland",
                                "email" => "dave.mcfarland@teamtreehouse.com"), 
                  $treasure = array("name" => "Treasure Porth",
                                    "email" => "treasure.porth@teamtreehouse.com"), 
                  $andrew = array("name" => "Andrew Chalkley",
                                  "email" => "andrew.chalkley@teamtreehouse.com")
                 );

    echo "<ul>\n";
names.
    echo "<li>$contacts[0][name]</li>\n";
    echo "</ul>\n";
?>
```

I get this error when I try to view a webpage running this script:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in index.php on line 15
Array[name]
```

Is there a built in function to convert this array to a string, or do I have a syntax error?

This is for teamtreehouse.com, so I assume I'm missing something simple.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11085570/3933332

Comment: put curly braces so that it'll be interpreted properly, the only interpreted part is `$contacts`, thus the error, wrap it so that it treats it as a whole. check out the link provided above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<?php echo $contacts[$alena]['name']; ?>
```

The problem is You have not create any array key is naming "0"

Comment: That is just wrong. "Try below code" Have you tried your own code?