# PHP associative arrays within if-else

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, could someone please let me know as to what I am doing wrong here:-

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'firstName' => 'Manav',
'lastName' => 'Saxena',
'users' => array(
    array(    'Name' => 'John',
    'age' => 24),
    array( 'Name' => 'Unknown',
    'age' => 22)
));

if($arr['firstName'] == 'Manav'){
    echo "Hello $arr['firstName']";
}

foreach($arr['users'] as $user){
    echo "$user['Name'] is $user['age'] years old!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Echo some string and multidimensional array element in one line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085570/echo-some-string-and-multidimensional-array-element-in-one-line-of-code)

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: What wrong do you mean? Make clear your question please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are simply messing up quotes while displaying. Change your code to:

```
$arr = array(
'firstName' => 'Manav',
'lastName' => 'Saxena',
'users' => array(
    array(    'Name' => 'John',
    'age' => 24),
    array( 'Name' => 'Unknown',
    'age' => 22)
));

if($arr['firstName'] == 'Manav'){
    echo "Hello $arr[firstName]";
}

foreach($arr['users'] as $user){
    echo "$user[Name] is $user[age] years old!";
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/840484)

Comment: this will not echo the content of `$user['Name']`

Comment: It will echo content. Try it.@C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅

Comment: I have added demo link too. Check it

Comment: yep my bad, i did not know this syntax exists

Answer (score 2):

Just `concatenate` the variable with string like below

**Method 1 :**

```
if($arr['firstName'] == 'Manav'){
    echo "Hello ".$arr['firstName'];
}

foreach($arr['users'] as $user){
    echo $user['Name']." is ".$user['age']." years old! <br>";
}
```

**Method 2 :** simple remove the inside single quotes .

```
    if($arr['firstName'] == 'Manav'){
    echo "Hello $arr[firstName]";
}

foreach($arr['users'] as $user){
    echo "$user[Name] is $user[age] years old! <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write like this,

```
if($arr['firstName'] == 'Manav'){
    echo "Hello ". $arr['firstName']." ";
}

foreach($arr['users'] as $user){
    echo $user['Name']. "is ". $user['age']." years old!";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It gives you a parsing error. To clarify things, try concatenating the values to the string.

Note that PHP searches for variables between double quotes but not between single quotes. So using single quotes here will give you a performance benefit.

```
if($arr['firstName'] == 'Manav'){
    echo 'Hello '.$arr['firstName'];
}

foreach($arr['users'] as $user){
    echo $user['Name'].' is '.$user['age'].' years old!';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error
replace your code with this:

```
<?php
    $arr = array(
        'firstName' => 'Manav',
        'lastName' => 'Saxena',
        'users' => array(
            array(    
               'Name' => 'John',
               'age' => 24),
                   array( 
                      'Name' => 'Unknown',
                      'age' => 22
                   )
            )
    );

    if($arr['firstName'] == 'Manav'){
        echo "Hello ".$arr['firstName'];
    }

    foreach($arr['users'] as $user){
        echo $user['Name']." is ".$user['age']." years old!";
    }

?>
```